# wxwidget Set window size to fit screen

Tags: wxwidgets, sizer

How to set application window size to fit entire screen automatically when the application start? Currently using c++ wxwidget GetClientSize but it only allows setting of absolute dimensions.

Cant find any functions or info for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DappyKape,

Use ShowFullScreen().

Check `display` sample for the usage.

Or call Maximize().

Answer (score 1):

Use wxMAXIMIZE in window style.

```
wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame(NULL, -1, _T("Caption"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wxMAXIMIZE, _T("window"));
```